# How can I install a Java JAR library via command line, and compile my program via cli?

Tags: java

I just started learning Java.

Since I know a little Python,I just wanted to "take the measure" of Java, and precisely how can I do something I already know with Python: download a webpage html.

Thanks to a StackOverflow question I discovered Jsoup.
I downloaded the JAR and....what should I do now?

I tried placing it in the same folder as my program, having chmodded +x to it, or placing it to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext`

I am trying to run this program

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
public class ParseHTML {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.wikipedia.org/").get();
        String text = doc.body().text();
        System.out.print(text);
    }
}
```

but it gives these errors

```
js_dwn_wbp.java:6: error: class ParseHTML is public, should be declared in a file named ParseHTML.java
public class ParseHTML {
       ^
js_dwn_wbp.java:2: error: package org.jsoup does not exist
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
                ^
js_dwn_wbp.java:3: error: package org.jsoup.nodes does not exist
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
                      ^
js_dwn_wbp.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.wikipedia.org/").get();
        ^
  symbol:   class Document
  location: class ParseHTML
js_dwn_wbp.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.wikipedia.org/").get();
                       ^
  symbol:   variable Jsoup
  location: class ParseHTML
5 errors
```

Thanks in advance

**EDIT 1**
Thanks to a comment I was able to compile via terminal, however it gives this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jsoup/Jsoup
    at ParseHTML.main(ParseHTML.java:9)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jsoup.Jsoup
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: I am running Ubuntu

Comment: Let **CLASSPATH** environment variable point to the location of your jar file, and sooner or later, pretty soon though, you are going to hear about **Gradle** and **Maven** for online ways of including JAR-CODE in your jar file

Comment: @ShayHaned Can you point reference of how to set the "CLASSPATH" you named in the comment? Running Ubuntu...Thanks

Comment: Link posted by **ivange94** would help you the best

Comment: Do not put libraries in `lib/ext` for one it is deprecated and will be removed in Java 9, and second it will mess up things in unexpected ways if you have conflicting dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will also need to add supporting jars i.e. jars used in Jsoup in classpath folder.

Download jar with dependencies from below link..
https://jar-download.com/explore-java-source-code.php?a=jsoup&g=org.jsoup&v=1.9.2&downloadable=1

Comment: in the specific? it throws error, see EDIT 1 in the question